# jQuery weird JSON behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

I'm getting a array of the selected checkboxes and push them into an array.

After that I `JSON.stringify()` the array and send it to my PHP script.

But the weird thing is that when I send the array variable, it returns strange things.

Here is the code:

```
var _items = new Array();
$('input:checkbox:checked.item').each(function () {
   _items.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: btn.data('url'),
   data: {_token: token, items: JSON.stringify(_items)},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function () {
    //
   }
})
```

When I console log the `_items variable I get a array back with the selected boxes like this:

```
["3", "4"]
```

In my PHP I do:

```
dd(json_decode(Input::get('items')));
```

But the strange thing is the `_items` variable returns an array of this in my PHP script:

```
0: 2
1: 0
2: 3
3: 1
4: 1
5: 4
6: 1
```

When I manually created the `_items` variable like so: `var _items = ["3", "4"];`
It does return the correct array..

**EDIT:** When I try to send it as a array it will return the same result as the `strange thing` above..

**EDIT2:** The code where I print the PHP array with. I catch the route with laravel (this is working as it should) and then I die and dump (dd) the input. Same as `$_POST['items']`:

```
Route::post('user/destroy/multiple', function () {
    dd(json_decode(Input::get('items')));
});
```

**EDIT3:** Strange things is when I output `Input::get('items')` it does return a JSON string, but for some reason I just can't json_decode it..

What can be wrong with the code...?

Comment: How are you printing out the PHP array? Please create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Have you checked `json_last_error_msg` for the `Input::get('items')` json?

Comment: If I `json_decode` it and then `dd(json_last_error_msg())` it returns `No errors`.

Comment: Do you really need to use JSON.stringify() in your Ajax call. Doesn't jQuery take care of that for you? An another thing, what if you var dump Input::get('items') without using json_decode?

Comment: Could you var_dump your $_POST, var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @pszaba The xdebug returns this: `'_token' string dXR1JCzKvyxPknialKn2PrDYtLXPNeJIGJrUQr0O (length=40)  
'items' string '[&quot;3&quot;,&quot;4&quot;]' (length=9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests:

> Note: Some JavaScript libraries such as Backbone may send input to the
>   application as JSON. You may access this data via Input::get like
>   normal.

So in your JavaScript you should do the following:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: btn.data('url'),
   data: {_token: token, items: _items},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function () {
    //
   }
})
```

And in PHP you should do:

```
Route::post('user/destroy/multiple', function () {
    dd(Input::get('items'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are encoding the array to Json in your javascript code, you don't have to do that, just send the array itself, the Ajax call will encode it for you. By doing that you are encoding twice the array to Json ! Replace `data: {_token: token, items: JSON.stringify(_items)}` by `data: {_token: token, items: _items},`

Comment: Im sure I've tried this... Well it worked, thanks. This little thing delayed me for like 3 hours or so, zzzzz..

Answer (score 0):

You want to serialize object, not array

Change your code:

```
var _items = {};
```

and something like this

```
$('input:checkbox:checked.item').each(function (i,v) {
    _items[i] = v;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Well, this is a JSON object, you should send something like this: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}